# Cpanel -WHM Default Login

Tags: azure, cloud, cpanel, whm

I have a Linux Server (VPS) which is hosted in Microsoft Azure, it has a default login for ssh as username: azureuser and password: (My Password). I wanted to play aroud and install Cpanel with this guide http://www.tecmint.com/install-cpanel-whm-in-rhel-centos/ I installed it successfully in here https://centsrv.cloudapp.net:2087/

Now, my problem is I can't login. I tried my defaut login on ssh and don't work. even username: root and my ssh password don't work.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use your root user password to Login your WHM panel. If you are unable to login your WHM with correct root password then I think there is an issues with the cPHulk. Might be your IP is blocked in cPHulk databases and due to that you are getting this login invalid issues.

You can try to disable cPHulk with the following command.

```
/usr/local/cpanel/etc/init/stopcphulkd
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/cphulk_pam_ctl --disable
```

Comment: i have the same problem and cPHulk is disabled. Is about Microsoft Azure virtual machines